# Is there a way to change all alpha channel together?

Tags: rendering, shaders

I have a rock inside a wooden box,I can't see the rock.But sometimes I need to render both rock and box,the effect I want is set both material alpha to 0.5.
If I have many materials,and want to set all alpha to 0.5,is there an easy way to do that instead of make it manually?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Python can access the nodes and set the alpha value, but finding the right node will be easier if they are, for example, all basic Principled BSDF setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add any additional nodes. Just script it. If they are all *Principled BSDF* (Let me know if there are other types and i'll find a solution), you can use a script with a switch variable that's either True or False. In the following script it uses variable `TURN_ALPHA_ON=True`  (for `alpha=0.5`) or `TURN_ALPHA_ON=False` (for `alpha=1.0`). Just paste the script in the Scripting Tab's [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) and set the variable `TURN_ALPHA_ON` to either True or False then click *Run Script*.

[image]

```
import bpy

TURN_ALPHA_ON = True

for m in bpy.data.materials:
    alpha = 0

    if TURN_ALPHA_ON:
        m.blend_method = "BLEND"
        alpha = 0.3
    else:
        m.blend_method = "OPAQUE"
        alpha = 1.0

    try:
        m.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[21].default_value = alpha
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!It's much better,almost like a built-in button.

Comment: awesome! good to know this was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.

1. Select any Principled shader node and hit CTRL G
   It will create a node group and enter it. Inside disconnect the alpha thread, like so:
   [image]
   Whenever you want to change the alpha for all objects, select the group in the node tree, press TAB and change the value inside the group.
   EDIT: As suggested by @L0Lock, you can simplify this setup by grouping only a value node and use it's output in any socket in any material you want.

In all materials that are supposed to change alpha simultanously, exchange the principled shader with this node.
Add -> Group -> Node Group (or whatever name you gave it.)

2. a bit more complex, but nicer, since it works with any shader node:
   [image]
   The Object Index of the object info node refers to the Pass Index of the object. If you want to change more than one object at the same time, select all objects that are supposed to change, hold ALT and set the index. Just to be clear, 0: fully transparent, 1: semi transparent. 2: fully opaque.

Then there are drivers, have a look at them online, the setup is a tiny bit more complicated, but the end result might suit you.

Comment: Instead of grouping the Principled node which blocks you from having any other parameter different without adding lots of group inputs, I would group a value node that's then plugged anywhere you want the same value. Making a less heavy setup, and allowing you to use that value not just for alpha but anything that needs it.

Comment: The best result I want is find just an existed option to do that,like in C4D,but it seems blender don't have.Your second way works well and easy to set.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @L0Lock Yes, that is much better. I was overcomplicating it.